# Perl script using Time::Piece terminates without output, without errors - how to debug?

Tags: perl, datetime

I'm using Perl 5.22 on Windows 10. 
I have data with time/date strings that looks like

```
12/31/09 08:40:00A
```

The data is in local time, and does not indicate whether the time is or is not in Daylight Savings Time, so I'm trying to determine that.  I am first trying to parse the string to a time value so I can use

localtime(time);

to [return the DST status as the 9th value](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html).

I'm trying to parse the time/date string with Time::Piece:

```
  my $parsedtime = Time::Piece->strptime($timestampstr, '%m/%d/%y %I:%M:%S%p');
```

When this line is un-commented, the script exits to the command line without any error or output. Even the "Opening filename" output to the console at the very start of the program does not appear.

If I comment out the line above (and the references to $parsedtime) the rest of the script runs, outputs to files, and exits normally.

What can I do to debug the use of Time::Piece?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with *"what can I do to debug ..."* - if you put your example data string into you specific use of Time::Piece it will clearly `die` with `Error parsing time at ...`.  The reason for this is the `A` at the end of the string which makes no sense (maybe you mean `AM`?).

Comment: I apparently have several issues. First was why STDOUT was not appearing. I found `STDOUT->autoflush(1); ` and now I can see debug output up to the failing line. I added `use warnings;`  and I am also getting warnings, but nothing about `Time::Piece`.  In my past experience `die` is supposed to print the message, but I'm not seeing it. I fixed the A vs AM issue with   `$pline[1] =~ s/A/AM/;
  $pline[1] =~ s/P/PM/;`   The input string is now `12/31/09 08:40:00AM`, but it still behaves the same way. When `Time::Piece->strptime` is executed, the script ends without error or any indication.

Comment: If it just die's without printing something then the problem is somewhere in your application, like redirecting or closing STDERR. Nothing is known about this program though so no help here can be provided. But you asked how to debug the issue and the answer is: isolate the relevant line, feed it the input which made it crash and then debug the issue outside the context of your program because this might just be in the way of debugging this.

Comment: You were right about "the problem is somewhere in your application". Curiously, the problem was in code further down the script that performed a comparison on a value that was unexpectedly undefined.  Adding 'defined' to the conditional expression fixed the early exit that appeared to occur in `Time::Piece`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To construct a local time, you need to use

```
Time::Piece::localtime->strptime(...)
```

rather than

```
Time::Piece->strptime(...)
```

So,

```
use Time::Piece qw( localtime );

my $tp = localtime->strptime("$ARGV[0]M", "%m/%d/%y %I:%M:%S%p");
my $is_dst = ( localtime($tp->epoch) )[8];
say $is_dst ? 1 : 0;
```

Output:

```
$ ./a '6/31/09 08:40:00A'
1

$ ./a '12/31/09 08:40:00A'
0
```

Note that your timestamp format is ambiguous. In a place that uses DST, there is one hour a year for which it will return the wrong result.

---

About the problem in the comments,

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use DateTime::Format::Strptime qw( );

my $format = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
   pattern   => '%m/%d/%y %I:%M:%S%p %Z',
   locale    => 'en',
   zone_map  => { CST => '-0600', CDT => '-0500' }, # Handle non-standard time zone names.
   time_zone => 'America/Chicago',                  # Optional. Convert result to this tz.
   strict    => 1,
   on_error  => 'croak',
);

while (<DATA>) {
   chomp;
   my $dt = $format->parse_datetime($_);
   my $epoch = $dt->epoch;
   my $local_dt_str = $dt->strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z");
   $dt->set_time_zone('UTC');
   my $utc_dt_str = $dt->strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ");
   say "$epoch $local_dt_str $utc_dt_str";
}

__DATA__
11/03/19 01:00:00AM CDT
11/03/19 01:59:58AM CDT
11/03/19 01:59:59AM CDT
11/03/19 01:00:00AM CST
11/03/19 01:00:01AM CST
11/03/19 01:59:59AM CST
```

Output:

```
1572760800 2019-11-03T01:00:00-0500 2019-11-03T06:00:00Z
1572764398 2019-11-03T01:59:58-0500 2019-11-03T06:59:58Z
1572764399 2019-11-03T01:59:59-0500 2019-11-03T06:59:59Z
1572764400 2019-11-03T01:00:00-0600 2019-11-03T07:00:00Z
1572764401 2019-11-03T01:00:01-0600 2019-11-03T07:00:01Z
1572767999 2019-11-03T01:59:59-0600 2019-11-03T07:59:59Z
```

Comment: Yes, solving the ambiguity in the fall is my next issue to address:  `"11/03/19 12:40:00AM CDT"<br/>
"11/03/19 12:50:00AM CDT"<br/>
"11/03/19 01:00:00AM CDT"<br/>
"11/03/19 01:10:00AM CDT"<br/>
"11/03/19 01:20:00AM CDT"<br/>
"11/03/19 01:30:00AM CDT"<br/>
"11/03/19 01:40:00AM CDT"<br/>
"11/03/19 01:50:00AM CDT"<br/>
"11/03/19 01:00:00AM CDT"<br/>
"11/03/19 01:10:00AM CDT"<br/>
"11/03/19 01:20:00AM CDT"<br/>
"11/03/19 01:30:00AM CDT"<br/>
"11/03/19 01:40:00AM CDT"<br/>
"11/03/19 01:50:00AM CDT"<br/>
"11/03/19 02:00:00AM CST"<br/>
"11/03/19 02:10:01AM CST"`

Comment: See addition to answer.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent example of timezone conversion - I've learned a lot!  I use Perl a few times a year for tasks like this, but I've never become a real expert like you.  I'm scratching my head over your use of `qw` in the `use` statement. I've searched on qw, but most articles are of the form "The 'quote word' function qw() is used to generate a list of words".  Can you point me to an explanation of the syntax in `use`?

Comment: [`use`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html). `use Module;` executes the module and calls its `import` method, which usually causes it to export a default list of symbols (subs). If you provide a list (e.g. `use Module qw( foo bar );`), it is passed to `import`, which usually causes the module to export those symbols. As a special syntax, `use Module ();` and `use Module qw();` cause `import` to not be called at all (and thus cause nothing to be exported). I like being explicit about what I import so the readers and I don't have to guess from which module a sub originates.