# Answered: Perl approach for resolving ambiguous data stored in local time without reference to DST status

Tags: perl, datetime, dst

This is a follow up to the [answer to a prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61310956/perl-script-using-timepiece-terminates-without-output-without-errors-how-to/61312374?noredirect=1#comment108577281_61312374), where @ikegami provides an example to convert local time with CST/CDT to UTC (Z).

He took my example pasted in the comment with limited formatting and created this source data:

```
11/03/19 01:00:00AM CDT
11/03/19 01:59:58AM CDT
11/03/19 01:59:59AM CDT
11/03/19 01:00:00AM CST
11/03/19 01:00:01AM CST
11/03/19 01:59:59AM CST
```

The source data in the comment was actually this (but was not readable because I could not figure out how to insert a multi-line code block into a comment):

```
11/03/19 01:00:00AM CDT
11/03/19 01:30:00AM CDT
11/03/19 01:50:00AM CDT
11/03/19 01:00:00AM CDT
11/03/19 01:30:00AM CDT
11/03/19 01:50:00AM CDT
11/03/19 02:00:00AM CST
11/03/19 02:10:01AM CST
```

The important distinction is that the DST tag is derived from the date and time, so it remains CDT whenever the time is between 01:00 and 02:00 regardless of whether it is the "first" or "second" occurrence of that hour in local time. That is the ambiguity to be solved. 
The data above is already the output of another script. The original source data looks like this:

```
11/03/19 01:00:00A
11/03/19 01:30:00A
11/03/19 01:50:00A
11/03/19 01:00:00A
11/03/19 01:30:00A
11/03/19 01:50:00A
11/03/19 02:00:00A
```

To resolve this issue, my first thought is to detect a time entry that is earlier than the previous entry, and force the DST flag to Standard on that entry and subsequent, until the calculated DST flag changes.

Is that the best approach, or are there other "built in" capabilities or library functions that might already solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote up this question but didn't post it before I developed the solution. 
Here is what I came up with for the ambiguity - I hope it helps someone else. 
Special thanks to @ikegami for providing [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61310956/perl-script-using-timepiece-terminates-without-output-without-errors-how-to/61312374) of using Strptime and strftime to create the final output in UTC format. 
This is the entire script, starting with a timestamp format like "11/03/19 01:00:00A".  The data records are trimmed to the timestamp in this example, deleting the data that follows.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# Parse local time stamped data files save in UTC Time


use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Basename;   
use Time::Piece;    
use Time::Local;     
use feature qw( say );
use DateTime::Format::Strptime qw( );

STDOUT->autoflush(1);

my $format = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
   pattern   => '%m/%d/%y %I:%M:%S%p %Z',
   locale    => 'en',
   zone_map  => { CST => '-0600', CDT => '-0500' }, # Handle non-standard time zone names.
   time_zone => 'America/Chicago',                  # Optional. Convert result to this tz.
   strict    => 1,
   on_error  => 'croak',
);


# Input file from command line.
open (INFILE, $ARGV[0])
  or die "Error cannot open $ARGV[0]: $!";

print "Opening $ARGV[0] for input     ";           


my $base = fileparse($ARGV[0],'\..*');
my $outfname = $base.'.csv';

if ( defined $ARGV[1] )  {    # If a 2nd paramater is given, use it for the output file
   open (OUT, '>'.$ARGV[1]); 
 } else {
   open (OUT, '>'.$outfname);    # Else name the output file with .csv
   print "opening $outfname for output\n";
 }


 my $prev_outtemp = 0;            
 my $lastparsedtime = 0;  
 my $ForceStdTime = 0;

 while (<INFILE>) {
  chomp;
  my $workline = $_;   
  $workline=~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;   # trim leading/trailing space
  my @pline = split(/ /,$workline);    #split input line into elements @pline[0] @pline[1] etc            

  $pline[1] =~ s/A/AM/;     # change A and M to AM/PM
  $pline[1] =~ s/P/PM/;

  my $timestampstr =  $pline[0]." ".$pline[1];

                                                    #    12/31/09 08:40:00AM
  my $parsedtime = Time::Piece->strptime($timestampstr, '%m/%d/%y %I:%M:%S%p');

  my ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) =  localtime($parsedtime);      

  my $tltime = timelocal( $sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon, $year );
    $year += 1900;
    $mon += 1;

  my ($dst) = (localtime($tltime))[8]; # fetch daylight savings time flag

  if ( $parsedtime < $lastparsedtime ) {      # Time discontinuity
            $ForceStdTime  = 1;               # force standard time during 1 hour in spring
        }            
  $lastparsedtime = $parsedtime;

  my $dtlocaltag = "";
  if ($dst and not $ForceStdTime) {
        $dtlocaltag = "\"$pline[0] $pline[1] CDT\"";
            }
   else {
        $dtlocaltag =  "\"$pline[0] $pline[1] CST\"";
            }

    print "$dtlocaltag   ";          

  if (not $dst) {
      $ForceStdTime = 0;        # reset force flag once localtime sees standard time
      }             

   my $dt = $format->parse_datetime($dtlocaltag);
   my $epoch = $dt->epoch;
   my $local_dt_str = $dt->strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z");
   $dt->set_time_zone('UTC');
   my $utc_dt_str = $dt->strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ");
   print " $local_dt_str $utc_dt_str\n";
   print OUT "\"$utc_dt_str\"";

   #  --- snip --- processing of rest of data in text input line....

   print OUT "\n";

}  # end of while loop

close (INFILE);
close(OUT);
```

Input data file looks like this:

```
11/03/19 12:50:00A
11/03/19 01:00:00A
11/03/19 01:10:00A
11/03/19 01:20:00A
11/03/19 01:30:00A
11/03/19 01:40:00A
11/03/19 01:50:00A
11/03/19 01:00:00A
11/03/19 01:10:00A
11/03/19 01:20:00A
11/03/19 01:30:00A
11/03/19 01:40:00A
11/03/19 01:50:00A
11/03/19 02:00:00A
11/03/19 02:10:01A
03/08/20 12:50:00A
03/08/20 01:00:00A
03/08/20 01:10:00A
03/08/20 01:20:00A
03/08/20 01:30:00A
03/08/20 01:40:00A
03/08/20 01:50:00A
03/08/20 03:00:00A
03/08/20 03:10:00A
```

Output data file looks like this:

```
"2019-11-03T05:50:00Z"
"2019-11-03T06:00:00Z"
"2019-11-03T06:10:00Z"
"2019-11-03T06:20:00Z"
"2019-11-03T06:30:00Z"
"2019-11-03T06:40:00Z"
"2019-11-03T06:50:00Z"
"2019-11-03T07:00:00Z"
"2019-11-03T07:10:00Z"
"2019-11-03T07:20:00Z"
"2019-11-03T07:30:00Z"
"2019-11-03T07:40:00Z"
"2019-11-03T07:50:00Z"
"2019-11-03T08:00:00Z"
"2019-11-03T08:10:01Z"
"2020-03-08T06:50:00Z"
"2020-03-08T07:00:00Z"
"2020-03-08T07:10:00Z"
"2020-03-08T07:20:00Z"
"2020-03-08T07:30:00Z"
"2020-03-08T07:40:00Z"
"2020-03-08T07:50:00Z"
"2020-03-08T08:00:00Z"
"2020-03-08T08:10:00Z"
```